# Is Ray’s "You’re welcome" a sarcastic remark here?

Tags: meaning, sarcasm

In *L.A Confidential* (1997), Bud White and Ray are having a conversation about the Night Owl murders, in
which cop Stensland died and all the bodies were found in the men’s toilet room:

> Bud White: Two of the victims were women?
>
> Ray: Yeah, Patti DeLuca, the night shift waitress, and a Susan
> Lefferts.
>
> Bud White: Susan Lefferts.
>
> Ray: Yeah, what about her?

Bud White hurries away from the scene.

> Ray: **You're welcome**.

Is Ray’s "You’re welcome" a sarcastic remark here?

Comment: You should be able to tell by the tone in which it is said and by Ray's expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You're welcome" is generally an acknowledgement of a thank you. In this case (and this is commonly used) it clearly implies that there should have been a thank you. Short answer: Yes.